# Conditional expectations in hidden Markov models

Tags: probability, integration, conditional-expectation

Assume that I have a random variable $Z \sim H$, and there is a second random variable $Y$ with distribution $G$ and $Y|Z \sim F$, then 
$$
G(y) = \int F(y|z)dH(z)
$$
Now, maybe $G$ is not known analytically, and I want to estimate $G$ based on knowing $F$ and $H$, and having access to a stationary and ergodic sample $Z_1,...,Z_n$ from $H$.

A natural estimator is 
$$
\hat G_n(y) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n F(y|z_i).
$$

Assuming that the first moments of all involved distributions are finite, does it hold that the expected value of $\hat G_n$ converges to the expected value of $G$, and how can I show this?

Comment: Well, as soon as the distribution of $Z$ is $H$, one knows that $E(F(y\mid Z))=G(y)$, hence the answer to your question is obviously "yes".

Comment: Hmm, I think I was or am confused. You are of course correct. So that the expected value of $\hat G_n(y)$ equals $G(y)$ then directly follows from the generalization of the law of large numbers, right? Furthermore, does the same hold for higher moments such as the variance?

Comment: Your turn: try to add at least some minimal personal input to your question.